# Rendering `html` when using `jade` templating engine, in Express

Tags: node.js, express

How do you render an `html` file while keeping the templating engine as `jade` ?

`app.set('view engine', 'jade');` is where i've set the templating engine as `jade` and I want to do something like

```
app.get('/world', function(req,res){
    res.render('profile.html', );
```

To render the `html` file.

I'm programming in node.js using express.js.

Note: i've already `require` `html` using `var html=require('html');`

Edit:

I understand `res.render` need not be used as `html` is already rendered. `res.send(profile.html);` gives error of `profile is undefined`

Comment: html is not supposed to be rendered. It is static, just send the file. Better you use it with express static.

Comment: res.send(profile.html) does not work. What is the syntax to send 'html' file using res.send

Comment: Read the file `profile.html` then send it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can render jade files (.jade) but not html files as the result will be the html. What do you mean by rendering the html file?

Replace your `res.render('profile.html')` by `res.sendfile('[path_to_the_file]profile.html')`

Comment: I want to see how some html files are rendered, without changing the templating engine. Its basically during the development. its a pain to convert all html files you find into jade before you can see what they look like.

Comment: I really don't understand...
You cannot render html file as they are already html. Just do res.send('profile.html') and it won't be rendered.

Comment: so instead of, res.render, i do res.send('profile.html'); ? Is not working.

Comment: what's the error message? you may have to indicate the path (it is implicit with res.render which is looking into the view directory, but not with res.render which is looking in the current directory)

Comment: res.send('profile.html'); simply writes "profile.html" whereas res.send(profile.html); says, 'profile' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `consolidate` and `mustache`  templating engine

`npm install consolidate mustache`

`var engines = require('consolidate');
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');`

Answer (score -2):

if you want to test the .html files, the easiest way to do it is to temporarily change the engine and add consolidate and swig modules

npm install consolidate

npm install swig

```
cons = require('consolidate'),

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Then you can simply render like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render("index");
});
```